# How to updated youtube video image and description while sharing link on whatsapp?

Tags: video, youtube, metadata, whatsapp

When I was trying to share my recently uploaded youtube video on whatsapp I realized that I need to change the video thumbnail on youtube, which I did. But the updated image is not showing up when I share my youtube video link on whatsapp.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it takes some time for whatsapp to update it.